# Android possible to draw line numbers in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-canvas

**Excluding word wrapped lines?**

What I want to do is have a class that extends `EditText` draw line numbers to the left of each line. On it's face this is quite simple by iterating lines `0` through `super.getLineCount()` and drawing an index at the start of a line.

But what I'm not seeing a simple say to do; skip over lines that are wrapped (lines that don't end with a `\n`). For instance in vim it would like:

[image: example]

What I'm using to do the above scenario (line count not skipping wrapped lines)

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

...         
        int count = getLineCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            getLineBounds(i, mRect);
            String num = String.valueOf(i + 1); 
            mPaint.getTextBounds(num, 0, num.length(), mNumberRect);
            canvas.drawText(num, NUMBER_LEFT_PAD, mRect.top + mTextHeight - 5, mPaint);
        }   

... 

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

How would I detect which lines are word wrapped lines and which are line-broken lines?

Comment: `getLayout().getLineStart(i)` will give you the position of the first character on a given line. Check if the `position - 1` character is `\n`, and don't draw a line number if it is. You'll need to use a separate `int` to track the drawn line numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Going off what Mike said, you can accomplish this by checking each rendered line to see if it's an actual line (preceded by a line break `\n`) or a word-wrapped line and only incrementing/drawing line numbers if it's an actual line.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int count = getLineCount();
    int lineNumber = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        getLineBounds(i, mRect);
        String num = String.valueOf(i + 1); 
        mPaint.getTextBounds(num, 0, num.length(), mNumberRect);
        if (i == 0) {
            canvas.drawText(num, NUMBER_LEFT_PAD, mRect.top + mTextHeight - 5, mPaint);
            ++lineNumber;
        } else if (getText().charAt(getLayout().getLineStart(i) - 1) == '\n') {
            canvas.drawText(num, NUMBER_LEFT_PAD, mRect.top + mTextHeight - 5, mPaint);
            ++lineNumber;
        }
    }   
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Improvising the code in @Lrdwhyt answer, I implemented subclass of EditText like this. It also sets left padding of EditText according to the line number text width.

```
public class LineNumberedEditText extends EditText
{
    private final Context context;
    private Rect rect;
    private Paint paint;

    public LineNumberedEditText(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public LineNumberedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public LineNumberedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context=context;
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        rect = new Rect();
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        paint.setTextSize(20);
        paint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        int baseline;
        int lineCount = getLineCount();
        int lineNumber = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; ++i) 
        {
            baseline=getLineBounds(i, null);
            if (i == 0) 
            {
                canvas.drawText(""+lineNumber, rect.left, baseline, paint);
                ++lineNumber;
            } 
            else if (getText().charAt(getLayout().getLineStart(i) - 1) == '\n') 
            {
                canvas.drawText(""+lineNumber, rect.left, baseline, paint);
                ++lineNumber;
            }
        }   


// for setting edittext start padding
        if(lineCount<100)
        {
            setPadding(40,getPaddingTop(),getPaddingRight(),getPaddingBottom());
        }
        else if(lineCount>99 && lineCount<1000)
        {
            setPadding(50,getPaddingTop(),getPaddingRight(),getPaddingBottom());
        }
        else if(lineCount>999 && lineCount<10000)
        {
            setPadding(60,getPaddingTop(),getPaddingRight(),getPaddingBottom());
        }
        else if(lineCount>9999 && lineCount<100000)
        {
            setPadding(70,getPaddingTop(),getPaddingRight(),getPaddingBottom());
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend it.([draw line numbers in edittext](https://mahbubzaman.wordpress.com/2015/05/11/custom-edittext-with-line-number/))

```
@Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            int baseline = getBaseline()
            for (int i = 0; i < getLineCount(); i++) {
                canvas.drawText("" + (i+1), rect.left, baseline, paint);
                baseline += getLineHeight();
            }
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I attempted to put effort into this question to avoid. The entire body of my question is explaining the difference between this (what I have now) and what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks anyway.